# Looking for iPhone equivalent code for Android HTTP request

Tags: iphone, android, web-services

I have android web service code, which has to be ported to iOS.  The android HTTP Request code has a line in it.

```
httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(myChallenge));
HttpResponse myResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

I am new to iOS Development, so I don't have clear idea on how to port or write the above code in iOS programming.  Any help will be really helpful.  Thanks in Advance.

Zach

Answer (score 2):

Look at ASIHTTPRequest (Google it). Very nice HTTP library with a similar set of functionality as you suggest you are familiar with. (Not the same, of course, but everything you would want to do, you can do with ASIHTTPRequest.)